# Exception when emit state to Bloc - Flutter Clean Architecture

Tags: flutter, bloc, clean-architecture

I have bloc which run validation function `inputConventer.stringToUnsignedInteger()` and usecase `getConcreteNumberTrivia(number)` in event `GetTriviaForConcreteNumber`.

code:

```
class NumberTriviaBloc extends Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState> {
  final GetConcreteNumberTrivia getConcreteNumberTrivia;
  final InputConventer inputConventer;

  NumberTriviaBloc({
    required this.getConcreteNumberTrivia,
    required this.inputConventer,
  }) : super(NumberTriviaInitial()) {
    on<GetTriviaForConcreteNumber>((event, emit) async {
      emit(NumberTriviaLoading());
      final inputEither = inputConventer.stringToUnsignedInteger(event.number);
      inputEither.fold(
        (failureConvert) => emit(NumberTriviaError(failureConvert.message)),
        (number) async {
          final result = await getConcreteNumberTrivia(number);
          result.fold(
            (failure) => emit(NumberTriviaError(failure.message)),
            (trivia) => emit(NumberTriviaLoaded(trivia)),
          );
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

In this bloc event, i get exception:
[image]

this exception happen when bloc emit(NumberTriviaLoaded(trivia))

in that exception description, there's a suggestion. but if you see my code, it already use that suggestion.

When running it, it should be emit `[NumberTriviaLoading(), NumberTriviaError(failure.message)]` or emit `[NumberTriviaLoading(), NumberTriviaLoaded(trivia)]`

did i miss something?

thank you

Comment: which part of the code should be looped? there is no array data there

Comment: even though I have done testing for this event block and it passed.
But when run, an error occurs as above.

Comment: inputEither is `Either<Failure, int>`

Comment: I see, I thought it is `List.fold`, and not `Eithet.fold` ...

Answer (score 1):

Try add `await` before the `fold` function :

```
await inputEither.fold(
        (failureConvert) => emit(NumberTriviaError(failureConvert.message)),
        (number) async {
          final result = await getConcreteNumberTrivia(number);
          result.fold(
            (failure) => emit(NumberTriviaError(failure.message)),
            (trivia) => emit(NumberTriviaLoaded(trivia)),
          );
        },
      );
```

Comment: inputEither is not `Future`